# Move operator for class that has a member with deleted move operator

Tags: oop, c++, operators

Class X has a deleted `operator=`

```
X& operator=(X const&) = delete;
```

Class Y looks like this:

```
class Y {
private:
    X variableX;
public:
    Y(int p) {
         variableX= X(p);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
class Z {
private:
    Y variableY;
public:  
    void functionF() {
         variableY = Y(42);
    }
}

Z variableZ;
variableZ.functionF();
```

This doesn't work because implicit `operator=` for class `Y` is deleted due to the fact that one doesn't exist for class `X`.

However, I don't really need anything moved anywhere. I want to instantiate class `Z`, at some point create object `Y` in place of member variable `variableY`, which would in turn create object `X` in place of variable `variableY.variableX`. Nothing needs to be moved, everything could be created at a memory location where it's supposed to end up.

Can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: “move“ has a specific meaning in C++, you're talking about the *assignment operator*. If you can't initialize an object, don't create it. Instead, consider a `unique_ptr<Y> = nullptr` that you can later point to an initialized object, or a `optional<Y>` where you later emplace an initialized object. In the future, you please ask code-level questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry, the question started as more design oriented, but it boiled down to this without me realizing that the target site has changed. It seems there is a concept I was unaware of in C++. This is what I ended up doing: `new (&variableY) Y(42);` This will create the object in memory which variableZ occupies.

Comment: That's placement-new. I've used it, but it's easy to trigger undefined behaviour with this due to subtle differences between objects and memory locations. `std::option` allows you to do that type-safely if you can use C++17. Otherwise, a `unique_ptr` might be the safer option. If you really want to use placement-new, first run the destructor on the old object before creating a new object in it's place: `variableY.~Y(); new(&variableY) Y(42)`